# Storing SSH login credentials?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, ssh, passwords

I am creating a web application that involves logging into servers via SSH and storing the details. Credentials will include root login details.

What are the best practices for storing this data safely and securely? Authentication using asymmetrical keys will be used be used but not the concern here.

The plan is to use MongoDB and Node.js.

Comment: You would need to encrypt the password fields using a password which has to be entered on application startup.

Comment: What encryption algorithms would you recommend?

Comment: AES256 is the standard nowadays. The operation mode should be either CBC or CFB. Contrary to what is told, a properly chosen password (10+ characters mixed of digits, lower and uppercase letters and special characters) which gets hashed in a secure way is pretty secure: The possibilities with characters from US-ASCII alone are 10^95 a number which is called a quinquanonaqintillion. For reference: the universe is bout 4.351*10^17 seconds old (a _tiny_  fraction compared to the number of possibilities), and even if you could do 100.000 checks a second, a brute force attack would take... ...long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to encrypt data that is extremely sensitive like that, is to use AES 256.

You'll basically want to AES256 encrypt the login credentials in some sort of file (like a CSV), and make sure the encrypt key is stored somewhere extremely safe (on a computer not connected to the internet, for instance).

This is really the only way to handle that sort of information.